# BigBlueButton URL is not loading in Android WebView

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, bigbluebutton

I've a requirement in one of my Apps which opens the BigBlueButton link in a WebView. The URL is:

**https://bbb.odin-health.com/bigbluebutton/api/join?fullName=Testdevice&meetingID=1600182496839&password=5FvAjuRt&checksum=b315e70fdabd4f3b56a1e33e500d0d259290653c**

When tried to load this url in webview it shows a White or Blank page. Here is the code

```
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);     
  

    webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.117 Safari/537.36");
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setAppCacheMaxSize( 10 * 1024 * 1024 );
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    String appCachePath = getActivity().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    webSettings.setAppCachePath(appCachePath);

    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    webSettings.setMixedContentMode(
            WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);


    webview.setWebChromeClient(mSWWebChromeClient);

    webview.loadUrl(getArguments().getString(Constants.BIGBLUEBUTTON_URL));
```

Am I missing something there?. The same url is working in Device's Google Chrome.

This is Logcat error log:

```
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/64 for video/mp4v-es
 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
W/OpenGLRenderer: load: so=libhwuibp.so
    dlopen failed: library "libhwuibp.so" not found
W/OpenGLRenderer: Initialize Binary Program Cache: Load Failed
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/0 for video/mpeg2
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/2 for video/mpeg2
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 1
E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 3
W/cr_MediaCodecUtil: HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**For Android**

Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65763780/7715349)

**For iOS and Swift**

Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73792727/7715349)

Answer (score -1):

android webview sends request with user agent is not fits bbb default configurations. in bbb documents.  Check /usr/share/meteor/bundle/programs/server/assets/app/config/settings.yml, where you'll see the browser (from the User Agent string) and the minimum version. add your webviews version there.