# Looks like you are using an older version of supported browser (Bigbluebutton)

Tags: android, bigbluebutton

I am developing a webview application to run BigBlueButton website on my app for video conferencing. I am facing an error **"Looks like you are using an older version of supported browser. Please upgrade Your browser for full support**" with blue screen. As I am new in android development. Please help...

**My code is**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static WebView webView;
    private static ProgressBar webViewProgressBar;
    private static ImageView back, forward, refresh, close;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        initViews();
        setUpWebView();
        setListeners();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.webviewBack);
        forward = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.webviewForward);
        refresh = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.webviewReload);
        close = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.webviewClose);
        webViewProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.webViewProgressBar);
    }


    private void setUpWebView() {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.sitesWebView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
        final String webViewUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        LoadWebViewUrl(webViewUrl);
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        forward.setOnClickListener(this);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(this);
        close.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.webviewBack:
                isWebViewCanGoBack();
                break;
            case R.id.webviewForward:
                if (webView.canGoForward())
                    webView.goForward();
                break;
            case R.id.webviewReload:
                String url = webView.getUrl();
                LoadWebViewUrl(url);
                break;
            case R.id.webviewClose:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void homeclick(View view) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();


    }


    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            refresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (!webViewProgressBar.isShown())
                webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            refresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (webViewProgressBar.isShown())
                webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            refresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (webViewProgressBar.isShown())
                webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            refresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (webViewProgressBar.isShown())
                webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetching data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            refresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (webViewProgressBar.isShown())
                webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            isWebViewCanGoBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    private void isWebViewCanGoBack() {
        if (webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
        else
            finish();
    }


    private void LoadWebViewUrl(String url) {
        if (isInternetConnected())
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        else {
            refresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    }

    public boolean isInternetConnected() {
        // At activity startup we manually check the internet status and change
        // the text status
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc5sh.jpg
```

Comment: What minimal version of Android does your application support? What version do you have on a device you tested the app with? What version of web browser do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `user agent` like this

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36");
```

and also add `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission into `androidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1):

**For iOS and Swift**

I added this line of code and it will works fine with me.
Add it in viewDidLoad

```
myWKWebView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! – Where did you get this information from?